# How to edit popup.html in script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I currently have my content_script checking for if the user has highlighted any text. Then I parse that text through an api and send it in the form of a message to the service_worker script. I then want the service worker script to set an element in the popup html to the text that was sent through the message.

My manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Paraphraser",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Automatically paraphrases highlighted text",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Paraphraser"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "contentScript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "script.js"
    }
}
```

My content script:

```
async function fetchData(text){
    console.log("hi");
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '2a513d4a51msh671908e60614124p125a31jsn338e77807b9b',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'paraphraser1.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
        body: `{"input":"${text}"}`
    };

    const res = await fetch('https://paraphraser1.p.rapidapi.com/', options);
    const record = await res.json();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(record.output, (response) => {
        return;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    if(document.getSelection){
        return fetchData(document.getSelection().toString());
    }
})
```

My service worker script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = message;
    sendResponse(user);
});
```

My popup's html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>paraphraser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text will show up here</h1>
    <br>
    <p id="popup"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I currently get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCWol.png)

> Error in event handler: ReferenceError: document is not defined at chrome-extension://kdiniggbkjgmjabohagdehaeeefcbmfi/script.js:4:5

Comment: Service worker don't have a DOM. You can't use the same script for popup and service worker.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I see, so how can I interact with the popup through script?

Comment: it is not safe\sane to public an API key in SO as in every other forum.  
Even if you had changed some characters of that key, remember that everyone can inspect the code of an installed extension and get the real key.